# How to cast __m128i to __m256i while setting upper bits to zero?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, simd, avx2

I want VC++ to emit code like this:

```
vpxor     ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
vmovdqa   xmm0, xmm7
```

In human language, I want a 32-byte `__m256i` value where the lowest 16 bytes come from another variable, and the highest 16 bytes are zero. An equivalent of `_mm256_castsi128_si256` intrinsic, only I need the upper 128 bits to be zero, as opposed to undefined.

Here’s what I’ve tried:

```
_mm256_setr_m128i( low, _mm_setzero_si128() )
_mm256_insertf128_si256( _mm256_setzero_si256(), low, 0 )
```

Both lines above compile into `vinsertf128`, relatively slow, 3-4 cycles latency, much slower than `vmovdqa`. Any workaround for VC++ 2017?

Comment: You don't actually want `vpxor  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0` first; simply writing an XMM register *with a VEX or EVEX encoded instruction like `vmovdqa`* (not legacy SSE) already zero-extends to full width.  That's how 128-bit AVX instructions avoid false dependencies without SSE/AVX transition penalties.  It's the same as writing a 32-bit integer register on x86-64.  In fact, the most efficient way to zero a YMM register is with xor-zero of the corresponding XMM, so [AMD CPUs before Zen2 still only need 1 uop.](//stackoverflow.com/q/43713273)

Comment: As far as getting compilers to not be horrible; good luck with that.  If MSVC shoots itself in the foot with `_mm256_setr_m128i` and the non-r `set` version, you're probably screwed.  Upvoted your question because it's an ever bigger missed optimization than you thought.  It's possible with 1 uop with zero latency on IvB+ and Bulldozer/Zen.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need `vpxor ymm0, ymm0, ymm0` because `vmovdqa xmm0, xmm7` already zeroes the upper bits of the target `ymm`/`zmm` register. That is unlike the legacy `movdqa` instruction, which you should not use in AVX code anyway.

Second, the choice of the particular instructions is the compiler responsibility. If your compiler generates inefficient code, consider reporting a bug to the compiler vendor. For example, gcc recognizes this pattern of intrinsics and generates the [optimal code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Ji5Pr).

As for MSVC, given that there is no support for inline assembler in x86-64 mode, there is no reliable way to ensure the particular instructions except to use a separately compiled assembler source. You may find some combination of intrinsics that generate the code you want, but that will be unreliable (and possibly invoke undefined behavior), and may change from one compiler version to another.

Comment: MSVC generally doesn't optimize intrinsics (for real instructions) at all; if you write `_mm256_insertf128_si256` you get `vinsertf128`.  Although apparently not always. 
 And BTW, your test forgot to use `-arch:AVX2` for MSVC; in one case it will use non-VEX `xorps xmm2,xmm2` before vinsertf128!  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HEcHDe.  You should use `-arch:AVX2 -Gv` (vectorcall calling convention so `__m128i` args are passed in XMM regs). **https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fm2heu shows that MSVC 19.21 and higher thinks `__m128i` args are already zero-extended to 256 and emits only a `ret`** x86 and x64

Comment: And ironically, GCC shoots itself in the foot with `_mm256_set_m128i`.  **Only clang doesn't suck at stuff like this (and optimizing shuffles in general).**  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9HNtpi (GCC, clang, and x86-64 MSVC 19.24)

Comment: Thanks, I've added the MSVC arguments and updated the answer with a new link. Yes, I agree that MSVC is especially terrible with vector intrinsics.

Comment: I think part of that is required by its overall philosophy: you can use intrinsics for instructions sets you haven't enabled, and do runtime dispatching based on an earlier CPUID check.  This means that it has to make sure never to put an AVX2 instruction on a path of execution that the source wouldn't run on a non-AVX2 CPU, for example.  This doesn't really justify all the badness, though; using another AVX1 instruction instead of `vinsertf128` would be reasonable.  And for example they generally don't even do constant-propagation through intrinsics, so it's more like writing asm I guess?

Comment: Regardless of the `-arch:AVX2` argument, MSVC does not zero the higher bits of `ymm` register. It is a codegen bug, plain and simple. Also, `-arch:AVX2` is required for the compiler to generate AVX2 code by itself (e.g. by auto-vectorising scalar code), but it is not required for intrinsics, AFAIK. If it was, the compiler should have failed with an error (and that would be a poor compiler behavior, as past gcc experience showed).

Comment: `-arch:AVX` is at least *highly* recommended for code that uses 256-bit vectors, to braindead code-gen that can cause SSE/AVX transition stalls, I think.  But yes it seems you're right; https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/smGnDC shows a test caller with a `__m256i` arg; it inlines into it without a `vzeroupper` or other instruction.  (A non-inline call to a function with only an `__m128i` arg appears to be saved from disaster by a `vzeroupper`, but a dummy `__m256i` second arg shows that MSVC's calling convention definitely doesn't guarantee zero-extended xmm inputs.)

Comment: It cannot have that guarantee because AVX code can be called from SSE code, and SSE code may be executed with dirty upper vector state. Also, I created a ticket for gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93594. Also see the followup https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93613. Hopefully, it will improve soon.

Comment: Also, the MSVC bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/911769/incorrect-code-generated-for-mm256-insertf128-si25.html